# Prevent Serialization of Base Class

Tags: c#, serialization

I feel like I should know this, but for some reason....

What is the preferred way to serialize a class that derives from a (perhaps abstract) base class, without having to serialize all the way back up the tree?  For instance, perhaps you cannot control the class that you are deriving from, but want to use serialization to clone your object (and your object only, not the base).

For example:

```
// This is a base class that is outside my control, which derives from
// some other base class that I know "nothing" about
public abstract class SomeBaseClass : SomeOtherBaseClass
{
    private string mBaseProperty = "Base Property";
    public string BaseProperty
    {
        get { return mBaseProperty; }
        set { mBaseProperty = value; }
    }
}

// This is the class that I do control
[Serializable()]
private class MyDerivedClass : SomeBassClass
{
    // Assume normal constructors, etc.

    // Here are some properties
    private string mDerivedPropertyOne = String.Empty;
    private string DerivedPropertyOne
    {
        get { return mDerivedPropertyOne ; }
        set { mDerivedPropertyOne = value; }
    }

    private string mDerivedPropertyTwo = String.Empty;
    private string DerivedPropertyTwo
    {
        get { return mDerivedPropertyTwo ; }
        set { mDerivedPropertyTwo = value; }
    }

    // And now a quick-n-dirty Equals override
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;

            MyDerivedClass compareTo = obj as MyDerivedClass;
            if (compareTo == null)
                return false;

            return ((String.Compare(this.DerivedPropertyOne, 
                                    compareTo.DerivedPropertyOne, true) == 0) &&
                    (String.Compare(this.DerivedPropertyTwo, 
                                    compareTo.DerivedPropertyTwo, true) == 0) &&
        }
}

// And while we're at it, here's a simple clone found elsewhere on StackOverflow
public static class ObjectClone
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {             
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");         
        }          

        // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object         
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {             
            return default(T);         
        }          

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();         
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();         
        using (stream)         
        {             
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);             
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);         
        }         
    }
}
```

As written, this will throw a SerializationException because SomeBaseClass isn't marked as serializable.

Comment: If you are using BinaryFormatter, then it is *by definition* fussy about the types, and will want to serialize everything. Are you able to use alternative serializers here?

Comment: This is inherently a dangerous operation, unless you know the internals of the base class. If the intent of the base class author was not to serialize the objects of that class, there is no guarantee that the object will be in a valid or even useful state after deserialization. It is not very meaningful to talk about cloning only the derived object. Inheritance means that any instance of the derived class must also be a valid instance of the base class.

Comment: MarcGravell, @JonasH, et. al.  This is more of an "academic" question - a result of me playing around with some code that I, well, inherited.  I certainly agree with your comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: use composition not inheritance. Extract the members you want to serialize into another class and make that one serializable. This will give you the control you want over the lifecycle and the extent of the serialization.

In general, it's a good pattern for serialized objects to be dumb data holders and have any additional logic added by wrapping them. This is reinforced with modern serialization frameworks like protobuf, thrift, avro, which will generate the code behind these serialized objects for you anyway and expect you not to muck with the internals of those classes through inheritance.

Comment: That sounds dumb. I have a class B inheriting from A (by design of the framework I use). I need to serialize B, but not A. There's no way to inherit B from `BSerializedFields` leaving only the logic, because that would require multiple inheritance. I could aggregate `BSerializedFields` as a field `Data` in B, but that would require accessing its fields as `obj.Data.FieldName`. I could create some mutators on B to access `Data`, but that would take a lot of code. I could generate that code, yes. But, hey, it's already easier to implement my own serializer.

Comment: So it's just some poorly written serialization routines in C#, not a good pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You may use XmlRoot("MyDerivedClass") attribute in the your ...BaseClass